# Angular 2 DRY: small syntax for a simple template

Tags: javascript, templates, angular

So I'd like to include large but not complicated html, which just contains 1 variable `item` which should be inherited from the parent.

Is there some simple way rather than having to create a whole component for it?

```
<div>Lots of nodes here, not just one, and also some item attributes {{item.url}}</div>
```

The parent would include this template at several spots.

What is the least amount of syntax required?

Answer (score 0):

how to show parsed **HTML** with `link` and `variable value`.

- **[Plunker-insert parsed HTML](http://plnkr.co/edit/ZBeSPqf4HUwLOeWSNfZJ?p=preview)**

```
<div [innerHTML]="myHtml"></div>

export class ParentCmp {

   myVal:string="micronyks";
   myHtml="<a href='http://google.com'>Google.com</a>" + this.myVal + " <p>Long text</p>";

}
```